# CSS how to use Flex positioning and fill content inside of the div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I have following slider:
[image]

I have issues with filling content inside of div. In this case in yellow div we can see button "Kempe2". I used break line (br) to put it in new line. When I use bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
<button>Kempe2<button>
</div>
```

button disappears below and it is hideen. This is the flex, and I don't know how to use it.

This works:

```
<div class="panes" [@slide]="activePane">
    <div firstPane>Hi
        <br>Kempe
        <br>
        <button>Kempe2</button>
    </div>
    <div secondPane>2</div>
    <div thirdPane>3</div>
    <div fourthPane>4</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<div class="panes" [@slide]="activePane">
    <div firstPane>Hi
        <br>Kempe
        <br>
        <div class="row">
                <button>Kempe2</button></div>
    </div>
    <div secondPane>2</div>
    <div thirdPane>3</div>
    <div fourthPane>4</div>
</div>
```

Here, button disappears and is probably pushed to bottom:
[image]

How can I use flex to put rows with bootstrap?

CSS:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panes {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.panes div {
  flex: 1;
  height:100%;
}

[firstPane] {
  background-color: #FFF897;
  width:100%;
}

[secondPane] {
  background-color: #6CE6CB;
  width:100%;
}

[thirdPane] {
  background-color: brown;
  width:100%;
}

[fourthPane] {
  background-color: purple;
  width:100%;
}

  button {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  slide-panel {
    /* max-width: 500px;  */
    height: 450px;
  }
  slide-panel div {
    font: 20px sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

 slide-panel .panes {
    border: 6px dashed #4990E2;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  }
```

Comment: yes it is horizontally centred with bootstrap v4.

Comment: I updated @VXp, have a look for description of problem